# query_posts , pegar a categoria e subcategoria

Tags: php, wordpress

Bom dia a todos.
Pela primeira vez venho pedir ajuda, depois de muitas tentativas (sou iniciante).

Eu estou querendo listar vários posts (poste_type chamado=familia_peixe ) pela categoria e subcategoria.
(Eu estou tentando aproveitar um loop que está funcionando em outra página, que mostra todos os post.)

```
<?php query_posts('familia_peixe_familia=familia_ordem_peixe & showposts= -1 & orderby=title');?>       
                            <?php if (have_posts()): while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>

                                <div id="box-categoria-ficha-peixe-conteudo">
                                    <div class="box-categoria-ficha-peixe-conteudo-faixa">                          

                                            <div class="h3-ficha-peixe-22"><?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'classificacao_peixe_ordem', true)):?><a href="<?php  $key="classificacao_peixe_ordem";echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);?>" title="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'familia_peixe_ordem', true ); ?>" >Lista ordem dos :  <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'classificacao_peixe_ordem', true)){echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'classificacao_peixe_ordem', true );} ?></a><?php endif?></div>


                                    </div>
                                        <div class="box-categoria-ficha-peixe-conteudo-titulo"><?php the_title();?></div>
                                        <div class="box-categoria-ficha-peixe-conteudo-texto">  <?php echo excerpt(80); ?>

                                    </div>

                            <?php endwhile; else:?>
                            <?php endif;?>
```

Este é o que eu pretendia 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você não disse qual erro está tendo, mas eu suponho que deve estar sem receber resultados, certo? Seu código atual está especificando a taxonomia `familia_peixe_familia` e o termo `familia_ordem_peixe` mas não especifica o `post_type`, então `query_posts()` está procurando no tipo `Post`.

Reescrevendo sem usar query_posts() porque [usar query_posts nunca é uma boa ideia](https://naousequeryposts.wordpress.com/):

```
<?php 
$consulta = new WP_Query( array ( 
    'post_type' => 'familia_peixe',
    'posts_per_page' => 100, // use 100 ao invés de -1 para evitar problemas futuros
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'familia_peixe_familia', // taxonomia
        'term' => 'familia_ordem_peixe', // termo
        'field' => 'slug',
    ) ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
) );

if ( $consulta->have_posts()): while( $consulta->have_posts()) : $consulta->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Obrigada Ricardo. O problema que tinha, mas que nao era 100% um problema era que estava querendo fazer com que em baixo de cada categoria mae estivesse as sub categorias. O código como estava escrito funcionava bem, mas nao pela hierarquia certa. Nao deu para eu fazer como eu queria 100%, mas deu para resolver de uma outra forma. Mais uma vez obrigada pela ajuda